# Trying to add a button on UI [ cloudstack] , But not refelcting in UI [ modifying CSS file & index file also]

Tags: javascript, html, css, button, apache-cloudstack

Any Advice/Help Thanks in Advance!!

Team,

Am trying to add an button for my front end page, Am modifying main CSS file by adding the button & am saving it & also am restarting the server & refreshing the UI page.

But chanegs are not reflecting in the UI, Tried changing other things also

No Luck, Nothing is refeclting

Any Suggestions/ Help

Answer (score 0):

zip the corresponding file after editing using linux command.

for ex: gzip -k cloudsstack3.css

Zipped files are sent browser cache for display.